# Using floor division and modulo together

Tags: python, operators

How can I find the positive remainder of a floor division. I know I can carry out floor division with the // operator and I know I can find the remainder with % but how do I do this together
For example, the positive remainder of 12//5

Comment: What output do you want at the end?

Answer (score 0):

The `divmod()` function returns `(a//b, a%b)` pair for input `divmod(a, b)`
So:

```
divmod(12, 5)
```

Would output:

```
(2, 2)
```

And this is right because 12 // 5 is 2 and 12 % 5 is also 2.